# Image changes, src attribute stays the same

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I'm experiencing a problem where the src attribute of an image element stays the same after ajax request. The element is an "inner" element of another element that gets "replaced" with .html(data) function @ callback function. The strange thing is that a new image is displayed as it should even though as I said the src attribute shows the pathway of the last image in the source code.

Here is the JS:

```
    $('.toplistimages').each(function(){
    var filepath = $(this).attr('src');
    var next = "next"
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?category=goto',
            data: {
                "filepath" : filepath,
                "next" : next
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#rightvotecolumn').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The content is replaced successfully, but src attribute stays the same.

Edit: I might also add that the right filename is displayed when I try to save the image that is displayed after the ajax request. I'm trying this on firefox and chrome

Comment: `but src attribute stays the same.` Says who? How do you get that information after the call? What kind of element is `#rightvotecolumn`?

Comment: Do you mean not src attribute but rather filepath variable value?

Comment: gotqn there are other content that is changed togheter with the image. maybe I should clarify that data in this case is new "content" inside a PHP file. What I do is that I include the php file with new desired content and send the entire file to the ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than checking the source code  by the 'View Source' option, I would suggest you to check it in your console using F12 in Chrome or on Firefox.

Because, the dynamic data which is added later cannot be seen in the Page Source.

Comment: question: How can I access this new data that has beenadded dynamically in conjuction withn e.g a new ajax request. because when I do that I get a null value when vardumping the POST data: Notice: Undefined index: filename in E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey\browse\index.php on line 318

Comment: If you are getting a notice, then I think you should correct your PHP code first in the index.php file.

Comment: You are so right. The problem was this. Thank you!!!! But still the whole source codes is the previous one even if the page is updated so i was scared I had to change all elements individually to access the new data from server-side. Terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of such behavior is that you get actual `src` value only once and use that value in each `click` event handler. To fix this, set up filename variable value on each click event:

```
$('.toplistimages').each(function(){
var next = "next"
$(this).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filepath = $(this).attr('src');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?category=goto',
        data: {
            "filepath" : filepath,
            "next" : next
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#rightvotecolumn').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Okay I'm very confused. the method I'm using to change content on a part of the page is to get the content from server-side and put this new data in a new php file including HTML and JS and send the entire PHP file back to the callbackfunction and replace the part of the page that is to be updated with this new php file. The content gets updated but all the values are the same as before the ajax reques occured. How can I get the values of the new content?